# send all "visible" drafts with VBA in Outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I automatically send out multiple (currently visible) draft items with VBA?
Please help, thank you.

Edit: It's a tough case, none of the items are in the drafts folder yet. These are generated emails that are on your screen, waiting to be sent.

Edit2: nvm, it's not going to help anyway. My script creates approximately 500 emails, and displaying the first 100 causes out of memory error. I opted to auto send them without displaying (it breaks the layout this way, but it's my only option for now.)

Comment: What does the your macro-recorded VBA look like when you try this?

Comment: I just reread your question, I think I may have misunderstood, what do you mean by "visible"?

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens that I ran into the same issue before and have code handy.  If you're not already in Outlook, you will need to add a reference in the VBA IDE, Tools ---> References... and check the box next to "Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library".

```
Dim oFolder As Folder
Dim oNS As NameSpace
Dim olMail As MailItem

If (MsgBox("Are you sure you want to send ALL EMAILS IN YOUR DRAFTS FOLDER?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "WARNING: THIS WILL SEND ALL DRAFTS")) = vbYes Then
    Set oNS = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

    For i = 1 To oFolder.Items.Count
      oFolder.Items(1).Send
    Next
End If

Set oNS = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code. Replace `Your Name` in `myFolders("Mailbox - Your Name")` with your actual name as it appears in the mailbox.

```
Public Sub EmailOutlookDraftsMessages()

Dim lDraftItem As Long
Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim myDraftsFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

'Send all items in the "Drafts" folder that have a "To" address filled in.

'Setup Outlook
Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolders = myNameSpace.Folders

'Set Draft Folder.
Set myDraftsFolder = myFolders("Mailbox - Your Name").Folders("Drafts")

'Loop through all Draft Items
For lDraftItem = myDraftsFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

'Check for "To" address and only send if "To" is filled in.
If Len(Trim(myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).To)) > 0 Then

'Send Item
myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).Send

End If

Next lDraftItem

'Clean-up
Set myDraftsFolder = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Source Code adapted from [this Question's](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?41304-VBA-code-will-not-send-emails-from-Draft-Folder-%28326-emails%29) answer.